# Is there the capability to store a number range within a column?

Tags: column, design

I am trying to identify the best column type to store a selection of number values and ranges of number, e.g. 10,000-20,000. A majority of the values will be individual numbers but some need to display the range. Is this possible to do in any way other than creating a 'text' column?

It seems a shame to lose the ability to deal with numbers numerically.

Comment: Currently there is no ability to store the Number Ranges as Number in SharePoint. may be its Shame but that the Product Limitation. if you have any specific product which identify Number ranges 10000-20000 as Number then you can user it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility of using one column apart from text to store that value. But you could split it into 2 number columns, Range Start and Range End. Maybe it will fit your scenario. I used that option and custom code later to display that value in one column using js.

Comment: Thank you Marek. Yes, I thought that may be the case. That is a good idea to use two columns